# 'collections.OrderedDict' object has no attribute

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, import

```
import pandas as pd

xl=pd.ExcelFile('/Users/denniz/Desktop/WORKINGPAPER/FDIPOLITICS/python.xlsx')

dfs = pd.read_excel(xl,sheet_name=None, dtype={'COUNTRY':str,'YEAR': int, 'govtcon':float, 'trans':float},na_values = "Missing")

dfs.head()
```

After running the code above i got the following:

```
collections.OrderedDict object has no attribute 'head'
```

Answer (score 0):

sheet_name = None will not work and you can combine reading excel file lines like this.

```
import pandas as pd
import xlrd


dfs=pd.read_excel('/Users/denniz/Desktop/WORKINGPAPER/FDIPOLITICS/python.xlsx',sheet_name=0, dtype={'COUNTRY':str,'YEAR': int, 'govtcon':float, 'trans':float},na_values = "Missing")

dfs.head()
```

Answer (score 0):

I have read the [API reference](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) of `pandas.read_excel`. `pandas.read_excel` method will return **DataFrame or dict of DataFrames**.

As you set `sheet_name=None`, you will get **All sheets** returned in the form of **a dict of DataFrames**. The key of this `dict` will be the sheet name.

So in your code snippet, `dfs` is a `dict` not a `DataFrames`. Obviously, `dict` has no `head` method. Your code should be like this `dfs[sheet_name].head()`.